Save a file in Databricks Workspace using Scala/Java
My goal is to run a Spark job using Databricks, and my challenge is that I can't store files in the local filesystem since the file is saved in the driver, but when my executors tried to access the file, it didn't exist because it is located in the driver filesystem.
I want to use the Workspace to store my file; DBFS is not an option for me. The issue is that in my notebook, when I attempt to store the file with Python code, it works perfectly, and I can access the file using the Databricks UI.
The following Python code works:
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Define the path where you want to create the directory and file
directory_path = Path("/Workspace/Shared/credentials/test")
file_path = directory_path / "abc.txt"

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(directory_path, exist_ok=True)

# Create and write to the file
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write("This is a string stored in abc.txt")

I need to do this in Scala, but I tried the following code and encountered an issue:
%scala
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, StandardOpenOption}
val directoryPath = "/Workspace/Shared/credentials/test2"
val filePath = Paths.get(directoryPath, "abc.txt")

// Create the directory if it doesn't exist
val directory = Paths.get(directoryPath)
if (!Files.exists(directory)) {
    Files.createDirectories(directory)
}
println(Files.exists(directory))

// Write the content to the file
val content = "This is a string stored in abc.txt"
Files.write(filePath, content.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)

println(s"Directory created at: $directoryPath")
println(s"File created at: $filePath with content: '$content'")

However, I am receiving the following error:
FileSystemException: /Workspace/Shared/credentials: Operation not permitted

Ultimately, I want to use Spark with a Kafka configuration and specify the location of my JKS file:
spark.read
     .format("kafka")
     .option("includeHeaders", IncludeHeaders)
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", topic.innerSource.bootstrapServers.get)
     .option("subscribe", parsedTopicName)
     .option("kafka.security.protocol", jobConfig.kafka.get.securityProtocol)
     .option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2")
     .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", MyLocationToTheWorkspace)

Do you have any suggestions on how I can use Scala to store my file in the workspace or in another location that all executors can access my JKS files?

What is /Workspace? Is that a Unix file path? Can you chown / chmod it?

I am already the "root", so think that will not help in this case

I doubt databricks lets code actually run as root user. Your Python code shows /Workspace, but your Scala code does not?

I edited the post, I used "/" same way as I used with python. I am trying to run with my notebook and by simple query of "whoami", I see that I am the root.

whoami locally isn't the same as when the code runs remotely in Databricks. On Mac/Linux, there generally is no /Workspace folder

Ithink you missed the point. I am not running locally I am using my instance profile in dbk same as we use when we run in PRD. We run with ec2 machine not with my mac. there should not be any difference.

When you login to EC2, wouldn't you be ec2-user rather than root? My point is that, you've not shared file permissions on the path /Workspace using commands like ls -lR /Workspace

this works on Shared as well as Single user cluster
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

val directoryPath = Paths.get("/Workspace/Shared/tmp/tmp")
val filePath = directoryPath.resolve("abcdef.txt")

Files.createDirectories(directoryPath)

Files.write(filePath, "This is a string stored in abcdef.txt".getBytes)




But in our case we are not running in single cluster, we have multiple nodes.

I tested it on Shared (Multiple Nodes) and Single User clusters.

I am getting this error: FileSystemException: /Workspace/Shared/tmp: Operation not permitted

Shared/tmp is my folder, please use the folder from your workspace.

I know, I created the same folder. Can yo share with me your cluster configuration please?

Added the config screenshot to the answer.

If you try to change it from shared to "No isolation shared" and try and let me know if that works for you?
